# Can have two database connection in one function?

Tags: java, sql

When I debug, I get this error :

> Column 'place1' not found.

I was able to verify that it has column place1 in sql.

Is it because I can not have two database connection in one function? I am unsure on how to further debug the problem.

**Case.java**

```
System.out.println("The highest value is "+highest+"");
System.out.println("It is found at index "+highestIndex+"");   // until now it works fine
String sql ="Select Day from menu where ID =?";
DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, highestIndex); 
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) 
{  
    int kb=rs.getInt("Day"); 
    System.out.println(kb);
    if(kb==k) // k is a value getting from comboBox 
    {
        String sql1 ="Select * from placeseen where ID =?";
        DatabaseConnection db1 = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection  conn1 =db1.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement  ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, highestIndex); 
        ResultSet rs1 = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs1.next()) 
        {  
            String aaa=rs1.getString("place1");  
            String bbb=rs1.getString("place2");
            Tourism to =new Tourism();
            to.setPlace1(aaa);
            to.setPlace2(bbb);
            DispDay dc=new DispDay();

         }
         ps1.close();
         rs1.close();
         conn1.close();

     }
     else
     {
         System.out.print("N");
         System.out.println("Sorry!!!");
     }
 }
 ps.close();
 rs.close();
 conn.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trace your code to see where you're getting the data.  The error is on this line:

```
String aaa=rs1.getString("place1");
```

Where does `rs1` come from?:

```
ResultSet rs1 = ps.executeQuery();
```

Where does `ps` come from?:

```
PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Where does `sql` come from?:

```
String sql ="Select Day from menu where ID =?";
```

There's no column being selected called `place1`.  This query is only selecting a single column called `Day`.

Maybe you meant to get the result from the second prepared statement?:

```
ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
```

There are *probably* more such errors.  Perhaps several (or many) more.  Because...

**Hint:** Using *meaningful* variable names will make your code *a lot* easier to follow.  `ps`, `ps1`, `rs1`, etc. are very easy to confuse.  Name variables by the things they conceptually represent and your code starts to read like a story which can be followed.  Variable names like `daysQuery` and `daysResults` and `placesResults` make it more obvious that something is wrong when you try to find a "place" in a variable which represents "days".

Answer (score 1):

In your second query:

```
PreparedStatement  ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

you are accidentally using the variable **sql** instead of your previously defined **sql1**. Replace it and it will be ok.

Comment: I get this: No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: @user5156075: Because you never set any values in your `ps1` prepared statement.  It has a `?` parameter which needs to be given a value.